snmpwalk: symbol lookup error: snmpwalk: undefined symbol: netsnmp_cleanup_session
i compiled Net-SNMP and ended up having a problem with snmpwalk which showed an undefined symbol and i ready tried to remove and download SNMP and i already upgraded
snmpwalk: symbol lookup error: snmpwalk: undefined symbol: netsnmp_cleanup_session 
I need to run this command

More information is required to help people answer this - e.g. platform, distribution, source package, build environment (and flags used etc.) ... but if you tried to remove then re-install via a package manager (for example) did you clear the local package cache?

@Bucky: In my case: Debian Bookwork running on an VmWare Fusion VM. The network bridge is set to be another ip in my LAN just like any other host. When I run snmpwalk -v1 -c public localhost I get proper response, but when I do snmpwalk -v1 -c public 192.168.0.86 I get the error noted above. I am watching the output of iptables -L --line-numbers -v on 192.168.0.86 and I see the counters increasing, so I know my host is hitting its destination.

@Bucky: Build environment is as per INSTALL file when downloading net-snmp-5.9.4 from sourceforge, all I did was run ./config, make and make install.
